# SQL Command - Advanced selecting

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

Using SQL Server

I have two tables

Table 1 contains each username and his manager

```
User    HisManager

John        Micheal

Gib          Mai

Sara        Mai
```

And Table 2 contains All records for the Users

```
Id UserName Comment Date

1  John     [Any comment]  [Any Date]

2  Sara     [Any comment]  [Any Date]
```

Now @ManagerX  is logged in into the a page

I want to retrieve

All records from Table 2 Where @ManagerX is their manager

Comment: You might want to rethink what you consider advanced selecting.

Comment: Agreed.  This is almost as basic as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * from Table2 a inner join 
(SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Manager = 'ManagerX') b ON a.User = b.Username
```

Comment: What does a and b represent ?

Comment: @SeRo these are aliases to the tables, so you don't have to keep putting table1, table2 in front of everything you want to select

Comment: You might want to put an `as` in front of them for better readability.  Even tho its not needed.

Comment: that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Table2.*
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.User=Table2.UserName
WHERE Table2.HisManager = @ManagerX
```

Comment: @SeRo, this is your correct answer.  Doing the query with a subselect will slow down the query and its not needed.  A straight inner join as squill has shown here is a straight forward and maintainable way to connect two tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table2.*
FROM table1 inner join table 2 on table1.user = table2.username
WHERE table1.hisManager = @managerX
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do it like this:

```
select 
    t2.* 
from 
    table2 t2 
    left outer join table1 t1 on t1.username = t2.username 
where t1.hisManager  = 'Mai'
```

this will return all the fields from table2 were the hisManager from table1 matches the name in the where clause.
you can add more fields in the select list if you like.